# Markup validation when page is generated with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, validation, angularjs, selenium, w3c-validation

We have a single page application created using AngularJS. We'd like to validate markup of that application. The problem is that markup is mostly generated with script, so that if we pass source code to validator, the result is only partial.

Currently we're looking into testing the page in the following way.

- Open the page with Selenium web automation library.
- Do some actions.
- Dump current HTML to file.
- Process it with standalone validator.

It's quite time consuming to implement this flow, as we would need to hardcode all the ways to use an application, so I'd like to ask: is there any other ways to do it?

Comment: you don't need to validate the DOM, or a serialized copy of it; the un-marred html source is what matters to validators. you'll likely end up with  more un-important "errors" than anything else due to outerHTML serialization differences with the source, limiting the usefulness.

Comment: https://prerender.io/ might streamline things for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `AngularJS` Your should **NOT** have to do validate every variation of your page as `DOM` changes with script in your Single Page Application as long as you stick with `AngularJS` programming model and stick to the following:-

1. **Validate every HTML file/fragment**.

   These are Angular templates/partials OR any HTML files you may have (index.html).
   Use `grunt` based html validator plugins like [this](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-html-angular-validate) so that grunt workflow can ensure that the HTML is valid even before it is committed in to your source code repository. Such plugins can validate HTML fragments.
2. **Use built-in `AngularJS` directives to manipulate the `DOM`**.

   e.g. ngSwitch, ngView, ngIf etc. instead of any custom stuff using jQuery or other mechanism.

   `AngularJS` already ensures a valid HTML DOM. That means your resulting HTML is always going to be valid.

Comment: this is a good answer, except that the last part muddies something important; that the DOM itself (after HTML5) ensures valid markup in the DOM, not angularJS in particular...

Comment: I am still researching a scenario where DOM would be invalid and without any errors the directive simply did not work i.e. the DOM did not become invalid and the end result was that my directive did not work. I will post any updates with that test.

Comment: the DOM simply cannot be invalid. we validate markup, not in-ram objects. to "validate the DOM", we would have to turn the in-ram model into a string serialization. The DOM simply cannot produce invalid markup from it's model because it's model is ideal, and it's ideal because it was parsed. Parsers skip or fix bad input, they don't allow it into the model they build, and as such, there's no way for broken markup to output. That said, HTML specifications themselves poses some restrictions the DOM is not obliged to follow, especially XHTML Strict, so it could depend on what "valid" means...

Comment: The problem is that neither `innerHTML` approach of Angular nor HTML in templates as strings help much. The proper way to validate a page is not to use Angular in first place.

Answer (score 2):

Have you consider using Angular e2e:

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.e2e-testing

This allows you access to get/validate elements from html like:

```
expect(element('#email').html()).toBe('something');
```

From Angular Documentation using jazmine:

```
describe('Buzz Client', function() {
it('should filter results', function() {
  input('user').enter('jacksparrow');
  element(':button').click();
  expect(repeater('ul li').count()).toEqual(10);
  input('filterText').enter('Bees');
  expect(repeater('ul li').count()).toEqual(1);
});
```

});

**Update 1**

Then you can try something like:

- https://github.com/peterjwest/html_validator/blob/master/demo.js

Comment: I didn't find a way to do markup validation with that library. It just tests whether markup is the same as expected. Though, there're situations when one forgot `data-` prefix, and the document is not well-formed HTML. I'm talking about such situations.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph What I am highlighting is that you can validate with this your syntax as well.

https://github.com/peterjwest/html_validator/blob/master/tests/validator_spec.js

Answer (score 0):

I call this GUI level Testing.  Visual Studio has an excellent browser recording and playback tool, which allow a tester to create Automated tests which validate anything the tester wants.

Here's a video: https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=ae5cd7309cccc43c&id=AE5CD7309CCCC43C%21183&sff=1&authkey=%21ANqaLtCZbtJrImU&v=3

You'll need to have the Premium edition to do this.   In addition, I've heard good reports about Selenium, in fact, MSFT themselves have endorsed it.